# Trying to build a dice game using front end languages i.e html,css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop a Dice game where the two dice roll simultaneously and generate random numbers. Here I used 3-D dice (not using Dice images) everything is working fine. I want to add one more thing: I want the numbers to appear on the front face of the dice on the screen like for example - 'the numbers are 2,3 or 4,5'. I need help in writing this code.

I don't know where to start. I want to do this using JavaScript, HTML, CSS.

```js
function rollDice() {
  const dice = [...document.querySelectorAll(".die-list")];
  dice.forEach(die => {
    toggleClasses(die);
    die.dataset.roll = getRandomNumber(1, 6);
  });
}

function toggleClasses(die) {
  die.classList.toggle("odd-roll");
  die.classList.toggle("even-roll");
}

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

document.getElementById("roll-button").addEventListener("click", rollDice);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}

main {
  background: linear-gradient(#454545, #676767, #454545);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dice {
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(8rem, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.die-list {
  height: 6rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 6rem;
}

.even-roll {
  transition: transform 1.5s ease-out;
}

.odd-roll {
  transition: transform 1.25s ease-out;
}

.die-item {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  box-shadow: inset -0.35rem 0.35rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0.5rem -0.25rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "one two three" "four five six" "seven eight nine";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.dot {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #676767;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -0.15rem 0.15rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  height: 1.25rem;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 1.25rem;
}

.even-roll[data-roll="1"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}

.even-roll[data-roll="2"] {
  transform: rotateX(450deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}

.even-roll[data-roll="3"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}

.even-roll[data-roll="4"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(810deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}

.even-roll[data-roll="5"] {
  transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}

.even-roll[data-roll="6"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(900deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}

.odd-roll[data-roll="1"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}

.odd-roll[data-roll="2"] {
  transform: rotateX(-270deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}

.odd-roll[data-roll="3"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-810deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}

.odd-roll[data-roll="4"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-630deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}

.odd-roll[data-roll="5"] {
  transform: rotateX(-450deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}

.odd-roll[data-roll="6"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-900deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}

[data-side="1"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}

[data-side="2"] {
  transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}

[data-side="3"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}

[data-side="4"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}

[data-side="5"] {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}

[data-side="6"] {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 180deg) translateZ(4rem);
}

[data-side="1"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: five;
}

[data-side="2"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}

[data-side="2"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: nine;
}

[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}

[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: five;
}

[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: nine;
}

[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}

[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}

[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: seven;
}

[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: nine;
}

[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}

[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}

[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: five;
}

[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: seven;
}

[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-area: nine;
}

[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}

[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}

[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: four;
}

[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: six;
}

[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-area: seven;
}

[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(6) {
  grid-area: nine;
}

button {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: none;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  justify-self: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .dice {
    perspective: 1300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="dice">
    <ol class="die-list even-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-1">
      <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="die-list odd-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-2">
      <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="roll-button">Roll Dice</button>
</main>

**CSS**
```

The code is available in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/ryancperry/pen/gymyyV?&page=1). You can have a look at the dice.

After the dice stop rolling it has to appear like below:

The Numbers Are - 2,3

The numbers are based on the front face of the dice.

Comment: Try this: https://codepen.io/jacobsun/pen/mgXXJr?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it, you just need to grab the values of each dice and display them.

I added the following div with a span for each dice value.  I use the ids to match which dice is which.

```
<div>Your values are <span id="die-1-val"></span> <span id="die-2-val"></span></div>
```

This is the only JS I needed to add, which I placed inside the forEach.

```
document.getElementById(die.id+"-val").innerText = die.dataset.roll;
```

Working example...

```js
function rollDice() {
  const dice = [...document.querySelectorAll(".die-list")];
  let dice1Val, dice2Val;
  dice.forEach(die => {
    toggleClasses(die);
    die.dataset.roll = getRandomNumber(1, 6);
    document.getElementById(die.id+"-val").innerText = die.dataset.roll;
  });
}

function toggleClasses(die) {
  die.classList.toggle("odd-roll");
  die.classList.toggle("even-roll");
}

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

document.getElementById("roll-button").addEventListener("click", rollDice);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
main {
  background: linear-gradient(#454545, #676767, #454545);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dice {
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(8rem, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  perspective: 600px;
}
.die-list {
  height: 6rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 6rem;
}
.even-roll {
  transition: transform 1.5s ease-out;
}
.odd-roll {
  transition: transform 1.25s ease-out;
}
.die-item {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  box-shadow: inset -0.35rem 0.35rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    inset 0.5rem -0.25rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "one two three" "four five six" "seven eight nine";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.dot {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #676767;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -0.15rem 0.15rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  height: 1.25rem;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 1.25rem;
}
.even-roll[data-roll="1"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="2"] {
  transform: rotateX(450deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="3"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(630deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="4"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(810deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="5"] {
  transform: rotateX(270deg) rotateY(720deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.even-roll[data-roll="6"] {
  transform: rotateX(360deg) rotateY(900deg) rotateZ(360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="1"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="2"] {
  transform: rotateX(-270deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="3"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-810deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="4"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-630deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="5"] {
  transform: rotateX(-450deg) rotateY(-720deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.odd-roll[data-roll="6"] {
  transform: rotateX(-360deg) rotateY(-900deg) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
[data-side="1"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="2"] {
  transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="3"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="4"] {
  transform: rotate3d(0, -1, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="5"] {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="6"] {
  transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 180deg) translateZ(4rem);
}
[data-side="1"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: five;
}
[data-side="2"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="2"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: five;
}
[data-side="3"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: seven;
}
[data-side="4"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: five;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: seven;
}
[data-side="5"] .dot:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-area: nine;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-area: one;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-area: three;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-area: four;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-area: six;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-area: seven;
}
[data-side="6"] .dot:nth-of-type(6) {
  grid-area: nine;
}

button {
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: none;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  justify-self: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .dice {
    perspective: 1300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="dice">
    <ol class="die-list even-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-1">
      <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="die-list odd-roll" data-roll="1" id="die-2">
      <li class="die-item" data-side="1">
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="2">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="3">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="4">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="5">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="die-item" data-side="6">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div style="color:#fff; font-size: 14px; margin: -25px 0 5px; text-align: center;">The Numbers Are - <span id="die-1-val"></span> <span id="die-2-val"></span></div>
  <button type="button" id="roll-button">Roll Dice</button>
</main>
```